# Using set and map to solve the mode problem?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

So I got this problem in my homework, which asks me to implement with both set and map respectively to solve for the numbers of modes in an array(to find the data that has the highest frequency of occurrence within a set of data). It also requires to test and show solutions for no modes, 1 mode, and multiple modes, These are literally all the instructions I have(The teacher isn't keen on being specific). As far as I understand, neither set or map allows for duplicates values, then how would there even exist modes? I am very iffy. Can someone give me some insights on this one, should it be doable? I would appreciate any pointers to kick this off. Thanks!!

Comment: What is "to solve for the numbers of modes in an array"?? Do you have something more??

Comment: Hi Aalejandro, I am sorry about the ambiguity. It is to find the data that has the highest frequency of occurance in a set of data.

Comment: For `set` take a look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/, and for  `map` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/. This a simple examples that can give you a starting point. Let me know how that works for you :D

Comment: I'm curious, is `mode` a defined term in set theory (or computer science)? Google doesn't seem to find anything for that term. And yes, neither set nor map allow multiple values (keys for maps) making `mode` kind of useless  (as by your definition).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really simple, you just have a map that keeps count of how many times each integer showed up and the iterate through the map to find the key with the largest count. The solution is the last one right here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/frequent-element-array/

As for the solution with the set, your probably best of using a ordered multiset that will keep things in the right order and then just iterate with a variable max count and current count. Replace most_freq (another variable) with the current element when current count is > than max count. That is basically the solution. I could code this up in 3 minutes, but I want you to do your homework.